# Can't detect the end of input strings

Tags: arrays, string, input, structure

This is to perform function of a phone book getting names and their phone number. For requested names it must print their phone number. The last out line prints infinitely for I cannot detect the end of input. I have used `\n`, `' '` and, `" "`, but nothing works. **HELP!**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct ph_book{
        char name[100000];
         double ph;
           }p[20];
 int main() {
        char temp[100000],ex[100000];
        int n,i,flag=0;
        scanf("%d",&n);
       for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s",p[i].name)  ;
       scanf("%lf",&p[i].ph);
  }
scanf("%s",temp);
while(temp[0]!='\n'){
    flag=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(strcmp(temp,p[i].name)==0){
            printf("%s=%.lf\n",p[i].name,p[i].ph);
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag==0){
        printf("Not found\n");
    }
    strcpy(ex,temp);
    scanf("%s",temp);
    if (strcmp (temp, "\n") == 0)
        break;

}
    return 0;
}/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
```

Answer (score 0):

The "\n" is not part of the input string of `scanf` function.
The following code will not enter the break (conditions is always be FALSE).

```
if (strcmp (temp, "\n") == 0)
    break;
```

If you wish to terminate input by empty string (when user press enter),
The following should work:

1. Replace `scanf` with `gets` (or better use the safe version: `gets_s`).
2. Compare temp[0] to zero, for detecting end of input sequence.

Sample code:

```
gets_s(temp, sizeof(temp)); //Instead of scanf("%s",temp);

while (temp[0] != 0)
{
    strcpy(ex, temp);
    gets_s(temp, sizeof(temp)); //Instead of scanf("%s",temp);
    if (temp[0] == 0)
        break;
}
```